# what could go wrong in the following code?

Tags: c, multithreading, buffer, buffer-overflow

```
char* function (char* s)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    strcpy(buffer,s);
    buffer[strlen(s)-1]='\n';
    return buffer;
}
```

for this function i think there are three things that may fail this code:

1. in case s is bigger than buffer will strcpy fail?
2. in case s is null then the third line in the function will fail?
3. what happens to this code in case of multithreading? will it affect only strcpy? (second line in the function)

what do you think?
are there more things that may fail? was i wrong at one of my assumptions?

Thanks

Comment: Most immediate, an outright buffer overflow on `buffer`, and invalid value for `s` (NULL), a non-terminated `s`, a close-proximity limit in stack space (adding 1K to the data call stack causing stack overflow). returning a local stack var as a function result.. In short, there are *far* more things wrong than right in this code. (Edit: and interestingly, multi-threading is *not* one of those "wrong" issues).

Comment: @WhozCraig your comment looks like a valid answer to me.

Comment: @WhozCraig What is the rigorous reason why returning "buffer" is undefined behavior?Plz tell.

Comment: @WhozCraig  only that it is local variable?

Comment: in case there are two threads entering the function, with no synchronization, is it possible that the string copy from s to buffer will be interrupted?

Comment: @SheerFish *Precisely* because it is a local-scope resource that is undefined outside of the function scope. The value returned is an address, which has linkage only while within the function body. This is markedly different than a dynamic allocation, which procures an address that has dynamic, and thus global, definition.

Comment: @Michal As written, I'm assuming `s` is not susceptible to outside modification while `function()` is executing. If it is, then it is `s`, and not this function that needs to be latched. If `s` is not susceptible to outside modification, then threading will not be an issue here (which is good, since there enough other things to worry about).

Comment: @WhozCraig Wow, that's a mouthful for me.I'll have to note down what you said about dynamic allocation.I wish StackOverflow provided a notebook where we could copy-paste important lines instead of "favoriting" the whole question.Dont' mind,I am copying this to my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as multithreading goes, if the memory pointed to by `s` is modified by another thread or becomes invalid (such as if it's freed by another thread), this function will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, `gcc-4.8 -Wall` gives you a warning:  `function returns address of local variable`

You cannot meaningfully return a local array (or string). At the very least, declare it `static` (but that is not multi-thread friendly).

Then, the `strcpy` should be `if (s) strncpy(buffer, s, sizeof(buffer))` to avoid a buffer overflow, and avoid dereferencing the null pointer (if `s == NULL`).

And you want to zero terminate the string after the newline, so code something like

```
size_t slen = s?strlen(s):0;
if (slen>=sizeof(bufber)-1) slen=sizeof(bufber)-2;
memcpy(buf, s, slen);
buffer[slen-1] = '\n';
buffer[slen] = (char)0;
```

Unless `buffer` is static, you want to `return strdup(buffer);` then the caller should ensure it becomes `free`-d later.

And you **really want** `strdup` or preferably [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf)

```
char* addnewline(const char*s)
{
   char* dynbuf = NULL;
   if (!s) return NULL;
   asprintf(&dynbuf, "%s\n", s);
   return dynbuf;
}
```

with the important *convention* that the **caller of `addnewline` is expected to ensure that the result is `free`-d**.

You should return heap-allocated memory, and you should have a convention defining who will free it.

You might even use [Boehm's GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/), i.e. its `GC_strdup` and not bother about freeing yourself the result.

If you don't want to use `asprintf` because it is GNU only, then code

```
char* addnewline(const char*s) {
  if (!s) return NULL;
  size_t sz = strlen(s);
  char* dynbuf = malloc(sz+2);
  if (!dynbuf) { perror("addnewline malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  memcpy(dynbuf, s, sz);
  dynbuf[sz] = '\n';
  dynbuf[sz+1] = (char)0;
  return dynbuf;
}
```

but you do want the convention that the result of `addnewline` is heap-allocated and should be `free`-d after the call.

Comment: `strncpy` isn't really appropriate for copying NUL-terminated strings (that's not even what it's for). `memcpy` is easier to reason about.

Comment: Unfortunately, `asprintf` is neither standard, nor POSIX, defined. It is a GNU extension only, and as such significantly limited it its portability scope. Too bad too, as I can see many times it would have come in handy as a general-purpose function.

Comment: Agreed, so I provided a more standard way of doing `addnewline`